# PHP String parsing into multiple parts

Tags: php, string, parsing

I have more than 2 lac records in DB like this: `[u'jazz', u' female vocalists', u' vocal jazz', u' jazz vocal']`
I need to parse out each record via PHP.

for example,

```
$tags="[u'jazz', u' female vocalists', u' vocal jazz', u' jazz vocal']";
```

I need to parse out 4 individual little tags, as:

- jazz
- femal vocalists
- vocal jazz
- jazz vocal

Comment: What is a "lac record"? How did you get `$tags`? Is that from a single database column?

Comment: is the `u'jazz',` a typo/cut and paste failure or does every entry start with `u` ?

Comment: Looks like a Python list of unicode strings. A simple regex would do instead of parsing.

Comment: yes, its single database colunm @Mike

Comment: @GOOG Then you have a design problem. You should store your tags in a separate table instead of some sort of string of text like that. This will save you many headaches down the road.

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`preg_match_all`**](https://www.php.net/preg_match_all)

```
<?php
$tag="[u'jazz', u' female vocalists', u' vocal jazz', u' jazz vocal']";
preg_match_all("~'(?:\s?([^']+))'~",$tag,$matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [0] => jazz
    [1] => female vocalists
    [2] => vocal jazz
    [3] => jazz vocal
)
```

Comment: suppose I have like this [u'sweden', u' black', u" rock'n'roll", u' hellacopters'] I need to parse out 4 individual little tags, as: 1. sweden 2. black 3. rock n roll 4. hellacopters